# Nifi Curl requests

Tags: solr, apache-nifi

How to make the following curl request to solr to do a partial update to a document through Nifi

curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxxx/solr//update' --data-binary '
[{
  "url": "https://community.macmillan.org.uk/cancer_types/kidney-cancer/f/78/t/136560",
  "sharecount"   : {"set":15}
}]'

Answer (score 3):

In NiFi you can use the [InvokeHttp](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.4.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/index.html) processor. You can either generate the JSON body with [GenerateFlowFile](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.4.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GenerateFlowFile/index.html) or get it from somewhere else (GetFile, e.g.), then connect that to InvokeHttp, which can be configured with the Content-Type header, update URL, verb (POST), etc. The response can be routed to a downstream processor such as PutFile, depending on what you'd like to do with/to the response.

Comment: It seems that InvokeHTTP does not support calling outside resources for proxy services. Is this correct? I know there are options for it, but they seem to not work.

Comment: in my case Curl command from redhat linux after (export proxy) works. but nifi, invokeHttp even with proxy host + port doesn't work. Is @nate right?